# How to handle refresh for data filtering in React useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I have the following code in my React component:

```
const { id } = useParams();
const { tripData, facilityData } = useContext(AppContext);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const idResults = facilityData.filter(facility => facility.id === id);

    if (idResults.length > 0) {
        setData(idResults[0]);
    }
}, [])
```

Where:

- [data, SetData] is the state that is used to handle populating a container
- facilityData is data accessed from my app context
- id is accessed from the URL

What seems to happen is that the data loads the first time without fault, but it errors out when hosted on the actual site (on localhost, it waits and eventually loads). To try to get a better idea of what was happening, I tried the following code:

```
const { id } = useParams();
const { tripData, facilityData } = useContext(AppContext);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const idResults = facilityData.filter(facility => facility.id === id);

    if (idResults.length > 0) {
        setData(idResults[0]);
    } else if (idResults.length === 0) {
        console.log(`id: ${id}`)
        console.log(`len: ${idResults}`)
}, [])
```

On localhost, on refresh, it console logs the actual id but then console logs the empty array before finally loading the data.

What I'm wondering is why this is the observed behavior. The "id" value seems to be constantly available, but the filter doesn't seem to run prior to the site loading. Is there a way to prevent this?

EDIT:

This is how I get the data (from Firebase)

App.js

```
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "./firebase";
const [truckData, setTruckData] = useState([]);
const [facilityData, setFacilityData] = useState([]);
const [tripData, setTripData] = useState([]);


 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async (resource, setter) => {
        let list = [];

        try {
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, resource));
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                let docData = doc.data();

                if (resource === "trips") {
                    docData.startDate = docData.startDate.toDate();
                    docData.endDate = docData.endDate.toDate();
                }

                list.push({ id: doc.id, ...docData });
            });

            setter(list);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    fetchData("trucks", setTruckData);
    fetchData("facilities", setFacilityData);
    fetchData("trips", setTripData);
}, []);
```

The app is at logi-dashboard, if that helps any.

**EDIT** Turns out the issue was with my hosting service, not the project. Go figure.

Comment: Where is facilityData coming from? That's what you should worry about. You don't need useEffect for the filter.

Comment: @EdvBeq oh my bad, it's also from AppContext. I'll edit my question to clarify that.

Comment: is facilitydata is constant or comes from any api ?

Comment: @sms it comes from Firebase. I'll update that in the OC.

Comment: then it must be asynchronous..  then you have to add the facilitydata as a dependancy in your useEffect..

Comment: @sms that doesn't seem to help any. There may be an issue with the data retrieval

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, it seems like the `facilityData` on which you are trying to apply filter and which is coming from `AppContext(Context hook variable)` is found to be empty array when the `useEffect` code is getting executed, this might be scene if you are hitting any API to get the data into facility but the API response is not coming till the time `useEffect` is getting executed or any other source which is not populating the `facilityData` until `useEffect` runs.

In that case, you can add `facilityData` in the dependency array of `useEffect`, which will help the `useEffect` execute again once the `facilityData` is populated(updated)

Comment: This didn't seem to fix it, but it does seem like there may be an issue with the original context population. I updated the OC with the retrieval method.